# Andengine resolution policy - inaccurate positions (gaps between objects)

Tags: android, andengine

I'm havin an issue with andengine. I have 64x64 blocks and I have to put them in the field (like chess field) just in side of each others. However I'm having an issue with positioning, which I guess cause inaccurate recounting positions from resolution policy (which I guess is caused by rounding float numbers and size of pixels). I use FillResolutionPolicy. If I tried to use FixedResolutionPolicy I haven't this problem any more. I believe pictures explain the best my issue.

[Image with FillResolutionPolicy](http://imageshack.us/a/img837/5615/pif3.png)

[Image with FixedResolutionPolicy](http://imageshack.us/a/img842/3097/8uua.png)